# Area map not working

Tags: html, imagemap

I have a [homescreen image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evJl4.png) that I need to have different sites linked to, but am still not able to make my area map work. I've tried reordering the  and  and double checking spelling. I have also double checked the coordinates. Thoughts?

```
<p><map name="epacbanner"> 
<area shape="rect" coords="0,336,156,489" href="https://www.google.com" 
alt="contact" />
</map> <img src="/content/epac%20banner_final.png" alt="epac banner" 
title="epac banner" width="960" height="322" img="" usemap="#epacbanner" />
</p>
```

Comment: Show us your code, contrary to popular belief the users here are not actually psychic :)

Comment: <p><map name="epacbanner"> 
<area shape="rect" coords="0,336,156,489" href="https://www.google.com" alt="contact" />
 </map> <img src="/content/epac%20banner_final.png" alt="epac banner" title="epac banner" width="960" height="322" img="" usemap="#epacbanner" /></p>

Comment: haha, sorry. It's been a long monday.

Comment: Next time, place the code in your opening post. a moderator will probably fix that for you this time.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [mcve].

Comment: If possible use an absolute URL for your image so we can see it too.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm not a web developer, so I'm new to this.

Comment: The url is through a password protected site, so I can't send. And I tried updated my information to make it more minimal, complete, and verifiable. If I'm missing anything, please let me now.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not with your HTML but the coordinate values, as you have specified a `rect` the first two coordinates are the `x,y` position of the top left corner of the shape. You have specified `336` for the `y` value when your image is in fact only `322` pixels tall (height) Changing that value to `0` places a rectangle at the top left of the sample image as shown in the second example below.

```html
<p>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/960/322" alt="epac banner" 
  title="epac banner" width="960" height="322" usemap="#epacbanner" />
  <map name="epacbanner">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,336,156,489" href="https://www.google.com" 
  alt="contact" />
  </map>
  
</p>
```

```html
<p>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/960/322" alt="epac banner" 
  title="epac banner" width="960" height="322" usemap="#epacbanner" />
  <map name="epacbanner">
    <area shape="rect" coords="0,0,156,489" href="https://www.google.com" 
  alt="contact" />
  </map>
  
</p>
```

Comment: pokeybit, thank you so much! It worked. I so appreciate all your help!!!